# Is there a way to see a diff of the current file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

I'm on a branch, and I'd like to see the diff between the currently-open file and the file's `main` version. I know I can do `GitLens: Compare Working Tree with...`, but then I have to find the current file in a (potentially-long) list of files. I want one command that just opens the current file's diff.

Comment: do you have installed the Git History Extension installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `GitLens: Open Changes with Branch or Tag...` command:

[image: open changes]

[image: choose branch]